# ¿Como corregir error al ejecutar comando webpack desde Node js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

Intento correr el comando webpack para compilar una aplicacion en react js, anteriormente trabajaba en ubuntu y funcionaba perfecto y me cambie a windows y al usar node js en windows, me genera el siguiente mensaje que no me permite compilar

** The CLI moved to a separate package: webpack-cli
would you like to install webpack-cli? **

y lo intento instalar ingresando la opción (yes) y no sucede nada, vuelvo a correr el mismo comando y vuelve y me muestra el mensaje de nuevo

Answer (score 1):

Es exactamente lo que te dice el mensaje, para poder usar desde la consola webpack, desde su versión 4, hace falta instalar el paquete webpack-cli que es el que contiene la funcionalidad relacionada con la línea de comandos.

Si tienes webpack instalado globalmente, usa

```
npm install -g webpack-cli
```

sino reemplaza el parámetro -g por --save-dev

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre es que pruebes lo siguiente:

1.- Instala de forma manual webpack

`npm install --save-dev webpack`

`npm install -g webpack-cli`

2.- prueba nuevamente y si no te funciona seria bueno que borres la carpeta `node_modules` y vuelvas a ejecutar `npm install`

3.- Posiblemente tu archivo webpack.config.js este fallando, seria muy util que puedas mostrar tu configuración para que sea mas fácil identificar tu problema.

4.- Si no fuiste tu quien utilizo webpack-cli explicitamente, busca que paquete esta tratando de llamar a webpack-cli y fíjate si es necesario que lo haga.